# Cannot link JSX script to html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">

  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/response.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a component using ReactJS to set elements in the navigation bar. The problem is that the script I've written does not link to the html file. The value returned to the html  tag is a list including nav, ul, and li tags.
How can I solve the problem of linking the script?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe the path to your file is incorrect, or maybe you have errors in your console, preventing the script to run. You should know better, we can just assume.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) will fail to load the file unless it’s served via HTTP, which means that you’ll now need a server to view your page. A good one is http-server which can be installed from npm with the following command:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

And started frpm your project’s root directory like so:

```
http-server
```

Your page will now be viewable at http://127.0.0.1:8080/